# How to preserve modifications in a composer library for future private projects?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, composer-php

I have made many modifications and fixes to a composer library that gets it's data from github , and it does have a dependency.

How can I preserve them easily while being able to get updates from package owner?

Comment: I would have overridden the changes instead of modifying the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fork the project on Github, commit your modifications to your fork, then point composer at it.

When new updates come from the original package owner, you can merge them into your project using git's standard merge features.

When I have a project I have forked on github, I will often keep two remotes on my local copy, like so:

```
git clone [url of my fork]
cd [project name]
git remote add upstream [url of original project]
```

When updates are applied to the original project, I do something like:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

Answer (score 2):

As my edit are rejected for absurd reasons. Fork like rjmunro suggests.

Then you need to refence your fork in composer.json

Example assuming you patched monolog to fix a bug in the bugfix branch:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix"
    }
 }
```

Take a look at the [VCS](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) part in the [documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/)!