# How to patch a Composer library?

Tags: php, composer-php

I installed a Github repo (not on packagist; the repo doesn't use composer itself) through Composer. After using it for a while, I found a couple of serious issues on the library that prevent's me from using it (Eg. it logs to a hardcoded directory, not writable on my end. yeah, yikes.).

Before I fork the project in Github, fix the issue and use it instead, is there a way I can have this package use a patched class instead of the existing? I was told that I could use PHP namespaces to override a class, without touching the original code.

Or maybe even a Composer feature?

Comment: Why not submit a PR to the original repo?

Comment: Best way is to fork it, file a PR, and use your fork until the PR is merged. See the dupe question for how to use your fork.

Comment: Alright, got it. Still, I saw that question before and a couple others (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245139/how-to-preserve-modifications-in-a-composer-library-for-future-private-projects) and I don't think that mine is a dupe, since it explicitly asks for a different solution that avoids the fork.

Comment: Mark Baker, the original repo seems abandoned, and I don't want to wait until they fix it anyway!